# Mobile navigation through links activates before finishing the scroll

Tags: javascript, mobile, touch, dom-events

I'm a newbie to mobile responsive sites and am playing around with converting one of my sites to a mobile friendly format.

One thing I've noticed is an issue with navigating on the mobile device. My site has an off-screen sliding menu of links (ala the one here: http://plugins.adchsm.me/slidebars/).

When I view the menu, I cannot navigate to the bottom of the links without activating one of the links first? To put it another way, it seems like the click event (on the link) fires before the div with the links navigates to the bottom.

Is there a way to delay the click event or wait for the scroll to finish?